# requirements.txt for pytorch for both CPU and GPU platforms

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to create a `requirements.txt` to use `pytorch` but would like it to work on both GPU and non-GPU platforms.

I do something like on my Linux GPU system:

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html

torch==1.10.2+cu113
torchvision==0.11.3+cu113
pytorch-lightning==1.5.10
```

This works fine and the packages are installed and I can use the GPU-enabled pytorch.

I wonder how I can modify this for the mac and non GPU users to install the non cuda package for `torch` and `torchvision`? Do I need to maintain separate `requirements.txt` files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## February 2024 update

Check https://pytorch.org/. You will see that "CUDA is not available on MacOS, please use default package". However, you can still get performance boosts (this will depend on your hardware) by installing the [MPS](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/mps.html) accelerated version of pytorch by:

```bash
# MPS acceleration is available on MacOS 12.3+
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

This command can be generated here: https://pytorch.org/

[image]

And in order to install different Torch versions on different platforms you can use conditionals in your `requirements.txt` like this

```bash
# for CUDA 11.8 torch on Linux
--index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118; sys_platform == "linux"
torch; sys_platform == "linux"
torchvision; sys_platform == "linux"
pytorch-lightning; sys_platform == "linux"

# for MPS accelerated torch on Mac
torch; sys_platform == "darwin"
torchvision; sys_platform == "darwin"
pytorch-lightning; sys_platform == "darwin"
```

This will install CUDA enabled torch and torchvision on Linux but the MPS accelerated version of them on MacOS

Comment: I don't think this works out of the box. I'm getting `ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.10.2+cu113` on my M1 mac.

Comment: CUDA is not supported on MacOS so you should get rid of +cu113

Comment: Yes, but this is the question...how should one have a standardized requirements file for such cases rather than different ones for each OS.

Comment: Use conditions in your requirements.txt as in my edit @Luca

Comment: '--pre --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu; sys_platform == "darwin"
torch==1.10.2; sys_platform == "darwin"
torchvision==0.11.3; sys_platform == "darwin"
pytorch-lightning==1.5.10; sys_platform == "darwin"'


it worked for me

Comment: first of all with `conda install --file requirements.txt` I can't install lines below in windows. and I get `CondaValueError: could not parse '--index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118; sys_platform == "win32"' in: requirements.txt`
but with `pip install -r requirements.txt` the lines are parsed, but doesnt install them
`--index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118; sys_platform == "win32"`
`torch; sys_platform == "win32"`
`pytorch-lightning; sys_platform == "win32"`