# How to install cuda pytorch requirements

Tags: pip, pytorch

I am making a public project. I am adding `requirements.txt` to it. but I don't know how its possible to add the pytorch `cuda` installation to `requirements.txt`.

1. with what line in `requirements.txt` this can be done?
2. will this answer work for any os?(windows, linux and iOs). note many macbooks recently support `mps` device instead of `cuda` device. so is this line also suitable for `mps` devices or not?
3. if its not possible to make gpu devices enabled for pytorch('cuda' or 'mps'), so what's the solution for automatic installing requirements of pytorch projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72949970/8031146).

However, I won't recommend putting this in the `requirements.txt`. CUDA version depends on the GPU and the driver version, so it would be better to ask users to manually install pytorch and cuda according to their environment.

Comment: thanks
do u know any python script to do this?

Comment: sorry I don't know why I had not read ur answer correctly, thanks again